# Retrieving list of items in creating a sales order using Suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I was able to fetch the options for select type of fields using the following code.

```
 for(index in fieldNames) {
     var selectFields = {};
     var field = record.getField(fieldNames[index]);

     if(field != null) {
        var id = field.getName();
        var field_details = {} 

        field_details['Type']=  field.getType();
        field_details['Label'] =  field.getLabel();

        if(field.getType() == 'select') {
            var Options = field.getSelectOptions();
            var selectOptions = {};

            for(var i in Options) {
                var opt_id = Options[i].getId();
                selectOptions[opt_id] = Options[i].getText();
            }
            field_details['Options'] =  selectOptions;
        }

        selectFields[id]=field_details;
    }
}
```

I can successfully fetch options such as customform, salesrep, and shipmethod. What I cannot retrieve is the **item** list to be added in the sales order. Based from what I can see in the docs, there's a sublist and subrecord, but there's no similar method to what I'm using right now which is the **getSelectOptions** method.

By the way, I'm using this as a RESTlet.